# Using external mustache partials in a brunch.io project

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, mustache, partials, brunch

I am working on a project that uses brunch.io and mustache for templating. I want to add mustache partials to the main index (which serves as a 'shell') to load in my content. I create the mustache partials in their own .mustache file and then add the tag on the index page (ie: {{> somePartial}} ) but what I seem to be missing is how to get the partial to render... Thats what I need help with.

Answer (score 0):

I’m using Handlebars.js implementation of Mustache in brunch apps, with it it's very simple: just register partial via `Handlebars.registerPartial()`.